# How can I publish multiple layers from same store in geoserver?

Tags: postgis, layer, geoserver

I have more than 2000 shapefiles stored in PostGIS database which are also stored in my geoserver store. I am able to show all the layers in the layer tab by connecting to the store and able to publish individual layers one by one. But I want to publish all the layers from this store. Is this possible to publish all the layers at eh same time? Is there any method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The GeoServer importer extension was designed to support mass layer configurations from a single store, check it out: https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Check out this tutorial. It has explained the procedure using cURL

http://benardonyango.com/2019/11/19/publishing-multiple-layers-of-geoserver-using-script/

Comment: Since you're suggesting to navigate to a blog, Your answer is a comment.

Comment: What if, I am a windows user?